# How to merge common data sets between two files

Tags: text-processing, date

I am attempting to merge two sets of data

file1 is a numerical julian date text file up to 366 to account for leap and nonleap years together.

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

File 2 is a data set which contains various missing days in the year

```
1 0.055980045
4 0.026198495
6 0.063033253
8 0.079462815
```

I am attempting to create a file 3 that looks like this

```
1 0.055980045
2
3
4 0.026198495
5
6 0.063033253
7
8 0.079462815
9
10
```

I have tried numerous `sort`, `grep` commands and have not been able to accomplish this. Any suggestions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `awk` for that purpose:

```
awk 'NR==FNR {missing[$1]=$2} NR>FNR {printf("%s %s\n",$1,missing[$1]);}' file2.txt file1.txt > file3.txt
```

This will process first `file2.txt` and then `file1.txt`.

- While processing `file2.txt` (indicated by `FNR`, the per-file line-number, being equal to `NR`, the global processed line-number), we read the "year-missing days"-association into an array `missing`.
- While processing `file1.txt`, we print the year and the number of missing days as found in the array `missing` (or the empty string if not present).

The output will be piped to a file `file3.txt`.

Comment: Just tried the suggests awk commands. Thanks for your help

Comment: You're welcome. If you found any of the answers useful, please consider accepting one of them (by clicking on the as-yet greyed-out checkmark below the vote counter) so that others facing a similar problem may find them more easily.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you could use `awk` to collect the data from the 2nd file and hash out the values in the first file

```
awk 'FNR == NR { map[$1] = $2; next } ($1 in map) { $2 = map[$1] }1' file2 file1
```